# pandas - merge df with multiindex on column with other df on index (without multiindex)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multi-index

My Google-fu didn't bring me the answer so I am posting my question here.

Let's say I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` and I want to merge them. `df1` has a multi-index on columns and `df2` consists of one multi-index column with an index. The index of `df2` has a name that coincides with a name (at level 1) of one column in `df1`. How to merge the frames using **one** column in `df1` and the index of `df2`? Simple example would go like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({('A', 'Col_1'): [1, 2, 3],
                    ('A', 'Col_2'): ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                    ('B', 'Col_1'): [1, 2, 3],
                    ('B', 'Col_2'): ['A', 'B', 'C']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({('C', 'Col_1'): ['X', 'Y', 'Z']},
                   index=pd.Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], name='Col_2'))
```

My aim is to merge `df1` on column `('B', 'Col_2')` with `df2` on index, preserving all the columns in `df1`. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding of the question you want df1 and df2 to be joined based on Col_2. Here is how you can do it. If some how i missed the part, please add in the comment.

```
#dropping the group header of columns from df1
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(0)

#Removing the duplicated columns in df1
df1 = df1.loc[:,~df1.columns.duplicated()]

#dropping the group header of columns from df2
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)

#Reset the index of df2 as first column
df2.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

#Concatinating 2 dataframes
new_df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Col_2'),df2.set_index('Col_2')], axis=1, 
                    join='inner').reset_index()
```

The final output will look like this

```
       Col_2    Col_1     Col_1
   0    A          1       X
   1    B          2       Y
   2    C          3       Z
```

Comment: That would be acceptable, but I need to preserve the whole data frame `df1` and your solution removes half of it :) Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: rename those columns with some other name and then follow the same merging steps.I think that will achieve the results. Please upvote the answer if it was helpful :)